# Dynamic Assignment of a value to Model object, dependent on user inputs in form in python

Tags: python, django-models, django-views

Im totally new in python and Django development, and is making a test run, where I have to make a Model object dynamic, and depending on a form input.

I want the T8 object to have the value of "hi", if the C8 object is = 1.

I have the following Models and views code:

```
    Models:
Class Patient
C8 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
T8 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)

Views:

def reg(request):
    form = RegForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect (reverse('behandlingsplan'))

if Patient.objects.get(Patient.C8) == 1:
    set (Patient.objects.get(Patient.T8)) = "Hi"
        print (Patient.T8)


context = {'ptid':ptid, 'form':form}
return render(request,'DentHelp/reg.html', context)
```

Any help?

Comment: And when user enter any other value it shouldn't change?

Comment: Not right now, I know you could use an else-statement for that. But right now I just wish to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `choices` in your `model.py` or in your `form.py`

models.py:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Hi'),
        (2, 'Your_value')
    )

    t8 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
    ...
```

When user enter `1` it input `Hi` in DB. And you could remove `if` from your view.
More information you could find in this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/choicefield-django-forms/amp/) or in [gjango documentatiin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/).